# Is gravitoelectromagnetism monopole or dipole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, dipole, multipole-expansion

Thorns said gravitoelectrism is monopole whereas gravitomagnetism is dipole. Others are saying the latter is monopole:
https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-09696-3

Which on is most likely right? Also Gravity Probe B assumed gravitomagnetism is dipole.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context by defining what you mean by each of those terms? It the present form of your question, it is hard to understand what you mean

Comment: An electric field has a positive and negative charge and so is the magnetic field. Gravitoelectric field (gravity) doesn't so I was wondering if gravitomagnetic field has the equiavelent of a positive and negative charge?